# PHP Soapclient xsi:type in response

Tags: php, xml, soap

I'm calling a method in a SOAP server, and the response includes the following XML tag:

```
<SelctedSupplements>
    <Supplement xsi:type="PerRoomSupplement" suppId="1000680" suppName="Upgrade" supptType="4" suppIsMandatory="true" suppChargeType="Included" price="0.00" publishPrice="0.00"/>
</SelctedSupplements>
```

The result I'm getting is the following:

```
object(stdClass)#156 (1) {
  ["Supplement"]=>
  object(stdClass)#157 (7) {
    ["suppId"]=> int(1000680)
    ["suppName"]=> string(7) "Upgrade"
    ["supptType"]=> int(4)
    ["suppIsMandatory"]=> bool(true)
    ["suppChargeType"]=> string(8) "Included"
    ["price"]=> string(4) "0.00"
    ["publishPrice"]=> string(4) "0.00"
  }
}
```

So all of the attributes are there, except for xsi:type="PerRoomSupplement". How do I get xsi:type of the Supplement tag? Do I have to get the last XML response and parse it through an XML library?

---

Before I submitted the question, I did some googling, and found a way to accomplish what I want, it may not be the ideal answer, but it does what I want. Here it is in case someone else is struggling with the same issue:

I know that the possible types of the Supplement tag are either PerRoomSupplement or PerPersonSupplement. What I did is create two classes with those names, and then map the SOAP response classes to my PHP classes. This way, I can easily know which type the supplement is (by using the get_class function)

```
class PerRoomSupplement{}
class PerPersonSupplement{}
$client = new SoapClient($url, array("classmap" => array(
    "PerRoomSupplement" => "PerRoomSupplement",
    "PerPersonSupplement" => "PerPersonSupplement"
)));
```

---

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xsi:type="PerRoomSupplement"` attribute is used by **SoapClient** to do the mapping of types in the response onto types in PHP. This also works with the help of the information in the WSDL file.

As without the classmap, there is no mapping class, **stdClass** will be chosen for the type mapping. Therefore unless you provide a classmap, the information from that attribute is already used (and lost) in conversion.

Next to a classmap you could also hook in [with a typemap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694712/367456) with which you then could obtain the information of that attribute however only indirectly via a callback. Additionally it requires that you create the objects your own.

So I assume that using the classmap is the way to go to preserve the information.